# Show status when installing Anaconda with Powershell

Tags: windows-10, powershell, anaconda

When installing Anaconda with Powershell:

Downloading.

```
Invoke-WebRequest https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-5.3.0-Windows-x86_64.exe -OutFile "Anaconda3-5.3.0-Windows-x86_64.exe"
```

When I run the code below, the process takes a long time and I cannot see any progress.

```
Start-Process -Wait -FilePath Anaconda3-5.3.0-Windows-x86_64.exe -PassThru -ArgumentList "/InstallationType=JustMe /AddToPath=1 /RegisterPython=0 /S /D=$env:UserProfile\Anaconda3"
```

Output:

```
Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName

-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------

     34       3      812       2096       0.02  11828   0 Anaconda3-5.3.0-Windows-x86_64
```

Is there a way to show the progress in Powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Note: In most cases, doing this with an external exe is not a thing for PS natively.***

See a similar discussion here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14739257/display-progress-of-exe-installation-from-powershell

All that being said.
In PS wget is just an alias, not the real wget.

```
Get-Alias -Definition Invoke-WebRequest | Format-Table -AutoSize

CommandType Name                      Version Source
----------- ----                      ------- ------
Alias       curl -> Invoke-WebRequest               
Alias       iwr -> Invoke-WebRequest                
Alias       wget -> Invoke-WebRequest  

# get function / cmdlet details
(Get-Command -Name Invoke-WebRequest).Parameters
Get-help -Name Invoke-WebRequest -Examples
Get-help -Name Invoke-WebRequest -Full
Get-help -Name Invoke-WebRequest -Online
```

If you are using the real wget, you have to fully qualify the path to it PathTo\wget.exe.

In order to show progress bars, you use the Write-Progress cmdlet.

```
# get function / cmdlet details
(Get-Command -Name Write-Progress).Parameters
Get-help -Name Write-Progress -Examples
Get-help -Name Write-Progress -Full
Get-help -Name Write-Progress -Online
```

> See: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Ff730943.aspx
>
> And this:
>   https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.03.powershell.aspx
>
> An Example of Using Write-Progress in a Long Running SharePoint
>   PowerShell Script
>
> https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18697.an-example-of-using-write-progress-in-a-long-running-sharepoint-powershell-script.aspx

However, to use it for what you are after, you need a way to determine the math of what the progress bar will use, as you'll see from the above articles.

Or, you can hard code a simple message in a loop, to look at the download location to see if the file is there, or if the install process is done, then exit the loop.

Comment: I knew `wget` in powershell is an alias for `Invoke-WebRequest`, but I usually use just type `wget` as it is less verbose.  I have edited the OP to avoid confusion.